# Using javascript to take the lowest two numbers from the total of a table row

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am attempting to write a page which has a table where the user can input a number in each cell, it would then display a total of that row with the lowest two values of that row subtracted. The code creates the array, finds the total of the array and the lowest 2 values (low and low2 in the code below). However when I try to take the two lowest values from the total, i get an error. I think i have found the error as testing the values using isNaN i find that the sum of the array is not a number, which doesn't seem to make sense to me. Here is where I got up to with the code:

```
   table = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    allrows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i=0; i < allrows.length; i++) {
        rowTotal = 0;
        rowArray =[];
        for (ii=0; ii < allrows[i].getElementsByTagName("input").length; ii++) {
            rowTotal = rowTotal + Number(allrows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[ii].value);
            rowArray.push(Number(allrows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[ii].value));
            var tots=rowTotal;
        }

        rowArray.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

       var low = $(rowArray[rowArray.length-2]);
       var low2 = $(rowArray[rowArray.length-1]);

       rowTotaladj = rowTotal- low  - low2;
            $(".row-total:eq("+(i-1)+")").html(rowTotaladj);
    }
```

Here is a link to a previous version of the page which correctly displays the total (rowTotal) but does not have the total minus the lowest two values in:

Any explaination as to why the sum is not a number and help with the code would be much appreciated.

Comment: `parseInt()` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can use the following code to achieve what you want:

```
// When an <input> is changed:
$('table input').on('change', function() {  
    var sum = 0,
        vals = [  ];

    $(this).parents('table').find('input').each(function() {         
       var val = parseInt( $(this).val() ) || 0;
        vals.push( val );
        sum+= val;
    });

    // Now sort the array:
    vals.sort();

    total = sum - vals[0] - vals[1];

    $('tfoot td').html( total );
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mqux6m9/)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a star!